# Setup Azure Function from Powershell

Tags: function, azure, powershell

In Azure CLI, there is [az functionapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest), but no such equivalent can be found in Powershell [AzureRM-library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/?view=azurermps-6.13.0#app_service) nor [Az-library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/?view=azps-1.6.0#app_service).

Using raw Azure resources, I've attempted something like this to create a function app on my Application Service Plan:

```
New-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' `
    -ResourceGroupName "MyRgName" `
    -Location "westeurope" `
    -ResourceName "MyFunctionName" `
    -kind 'functionapp' `
    -Properties @{ServerFarmId="abc-123"; alwaysOn=$True;} `
    -ApiVersion '2018-11-01' `
    -Force;
```

It almost works, but doesn't create a 100% working Function App. Azure Portal will spit lots of errors and warnings, for example from missing Host Keys.

Alternatives:

- ARM-templates. What to put into a template to successfully create Azure Function? I have no idea. The one generated by Azure Portal is useless.
- Azure Portal: Not really handy approach for environment setup from Azure DevOps release pipeline, but it will create a fully working Function App.

The question is: How to create a Function App from a Powershell script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am doing the exact same thing to create a dev sandbox environment.

Provisioning function apps is a gap in the Az Powershell module but it does appear to be possible.

I provisioned my function app by following the steps here https://clouddeveloper.space/2017/10/26/deploy-azure-function-using-powershell/ but changed it to use an existing app service plan instead of consumption plan.

```
$AppServicePlan = "abc-123"
$AppInsightsKey = "your key here"
$ResourceGroup = "MyRgName"
$Location = "westeurope"
$FunctionAppName = "MyFunctionName"
$AzFunctionAppStorageAccountName = "MyFunctionAppStorageAccountName"
$FunctionAppSettings = @{
    ServerFarmId="/subscriptions/<GUID>/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$AppServicePlan";
    alwaysOn=$True;
}

# Provision the function app service
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Location $Location -ResourceName $FunctionAppName -ResourceType "microsoft.web/sites" -Kind "functionapp" -Properties $FunctionAppSettings -Force | Out-Null

$AzFunctionAppStorageAccountKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -AccountName $AzFunctionAppStorageAccountName | Where-Object { $_.KeyName -eq "Key1" } | Select-Object Value
$AzFunctionAppStorageAccountConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$AzFunctionAppStorageAccountName;AccountKey=$($AzFunctionAppStorageAccountKey.Value)"
$AzFunctionAppSettings = @{
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = $AppInsightsKey;
    AzureWebJobsDashboard = $AzFunctionAppStorageAccountConnectionString;
    AzureWebJobsStorage = $AzFunctionAppStorageAccountConnectionString;
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~2";
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "dotnet";
}

# Set the correct application settings on the function app
Set-AzWebApp -Name $FunctionAppName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -AppSettings $AzFunctionAppSettings | Out-Null
```

Comment: This solution is very close what I had. There are more application settings, but it still yields "Internal Server Error" on missing Host Keys. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see that.   Where are you seeing internal server error?  What host keys do you see?

Comment: The internal error I see is about missing host keys. That implies lack of host keys, as in there are no host keys to be seen.

Comment: I have a code which does work to my liking. Since my Powershell script wasn't radically changed, I must assume that something changed on Azure end. An alternative explanation is, that after fixing the bug of my canary deployment slot not using the same ASP, everything simply started working as expected.

Comment: @JariTurkia I was just wondering about reproduction steps to see the error, I do see two host keys on the `Manage` tab in the Azure portal, `_master` and `default`.  Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: I want to add that before this script snippet, I am building a fresh storage account, and afterwards I am deploying my function app as a class library so the deployed environment is completely rebuilt from scratch.

Comment: If this was an easy one, I probably wouldn't ask assistance here. :) I have an idempotent script for creating environment and maintaining settings on a run. The sequence I had there would create an Azure Function App with various degrees of failure. Maybe its my sequence of creating Function App and a deployment slot for it, I'm not sure. Maybe its my particular set of configuration settings to get it always on, 64-bit and disabled FTP. Since this is for a project, there is limited time on how much time to invest on investigating and I cannot pursue this no longer.

Answer (score 4):

This might help:
To create an Azure Function we have dependency over "Storage Account", "Service Plan", "a resource group" and "Application Insight"(optional). Below i am initially defining variables. Post that i am checking if Resource group exist. If not it will create a new one. Post which i created Azure Storage Account, Service Plan and Application Insight. In Azure function we need to select Runtime Stack which can be "Java"/"DotNet"/"Python" etc. Here I am using "Dotnet". Azure Function requires Storage Account keys to link the same, which is extracted below under variables "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" etc. To link AppInsight with Function we need to map Application_Insight_InstrumentationKey. Please follow inline comments :

```
#=============Defining All Variables=========
$location = 'Southeast Asia'
$resourceGroupName = 'functionrgnew1'
$storageAccount = 'functionsasdnewqq1'
$subscriptionId = '<id>'
$functionAppName = 'functionapppsdfsdnew1'
$appInsightsName = 'appinsightnameprdad' 
$appServicePlanName = 'functionappplan'
$tier = 'Premium'

#========Creating Azure Resource Group========
$resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $resourceGroupName }
if ($resourceGroup -eq $null)
{
  New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location -force
}

#selecting default azure subscription by name
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID $subscriptionId
Set-AzContext $subscriptionId

#========Creating Azure Storage Account========
if(!(Test-AzureName -Storage $storageAccount))
{
  New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccount -Location $location -SkuName "Standard_LRS"
}

#========Creating App Service Plan============
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appServicePlanName -Location $location -Tier $tier
$functionAppSettings = @{
    ServerFarmId="/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$appServicePlanName";
    alwaysOn=$True;
}

#========Creating Azure Function========
$functionAppResource = Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_.ResourceName -eq $functionAppName -And $_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Web/Sites" }
if ($functionAppResource -eq $null)
{
  New-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' -ResourceName $functionAppName -kind 'functionapp' -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Properties $functionAppSettings -force
}

#========Creating AppInsight Resource========
New-AzApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appInsightsName -Location $location
$resource = Get-AzResource -Name $appInsightsName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/components"
$details = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId
$appInsightsKey = $details.Properties.InstrumentationKey

#========Retrieving Keys========
$keys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccount
$accountKey = $keys | Where-Object { $_.KeyName -eq 'Key1' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
$storageAccountConnectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName='+$storageAccount+';AccountKey='+$accountKey

#========Defining Azure Function Settings========
$AppSettings =@{}
$AppSettings =@{'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY' = $appInsightsKey;
                'AzureWebJobsDashboard' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
                'AzureWebJobsStorage' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
                'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' = '~2';
                'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' = 'dotnet';
                'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING' = $storageAccountConnectionString;
                'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE' = $storageAccount;}
Set-AzWebApp -Name $functionAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AppSettings $AppSettings
```

Comment: Please add details on your solution so everyone can understand your answer. Providing only code isn't sufficient

Comment: thanks. i edited the same with a short description of solution

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this from PowerShell is to use an ARM template, rather than try to create each resource individually. You can find an example template [here](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/FunctionsGitHub/blob/9d341efe5ca4d16b9a55ae626937791cfa99fb82/azuredeploy.json). It also hooks up the app to github, but you can leave out that part if you just want an empty app

Comment: Are you sure this will work? It is using API-versions "2015-05-01-preview" and "2016-03-01". Also, "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~1", which is not what I'm using. My thinking is, that this is equally useless ARM-template as the one Azure Portal (mis)generates. It would be helpful, if something couple years younger was made available.