# Setup and deploy Azure function using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, azure-functions

I try to setup and deploy Azure Function by using PowerShell script based on this topic: [Setup Azure Function from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492614/setup-azure-function-from-powershell)

My script looks like this:

```
#=============Defining All Variables=========
$location = 'Central US'
$resourceGroupName = 'MyResourceGroup'
$subscriptionId = 'MysubscriptionId'
$functionAppName = 'MyfunctionAppName'
$appServicePlanName = 'ASP-test-8b50'
$tier = 'Dynamic'
$archivePath = 'd:\TestAzureFunc.zip'

Connect-AzAccount

#========Creating Azure Resource Group========
$resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $resourceGroupName }
if ($resourceGroup -eq $null)
{
  New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location -force
}
#selecting default azure subscription by name
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID $subscriptionId
Set-AzContext $subscriptionId


#========Creating App Service Plan============
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appServicePlanName -Location $location -Tier $tier
$functionAppSettings = @{
    ServerFarmId="/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$appServicePlanName";
    alwaysOn=$True;
}

#========Creating Azure Function========
$functionAppResource = Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_.ResourceName -eq $functionAppName -And $_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Web/Sites" }
if ($functionAppResource -eq $null)
{
  New-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' -ResourceName $functionAppName -kind 'functionapp' -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Properties $functionAppSettings -force
}
#========Defining Azure Function Settings========
$AppSettings =@{}
$AppSettings =@{'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION' = '~2';
                'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' = 'dotnet';}
Set-AzWebApp -Name $functionAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AppSettings $AppSettings

#========Deploy Azure Function from zip========
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName -ArchivePath $archivePath
```

The script works without errors. Resource group and Function App created as needed. But the list of functions of the Function App is empty.
Function details here:
[image]
My intuition tells me that I've forgotten something. But I don't know what.

Could you advise me on how to deploy my Azure function properly?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow ,

Looking at your script we need to ensure that we are providing function app configuration as below `cmdlts` the link you followed:-

```
$AzFunctionAppSettings = @{
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = $AppInsightsKey;
    AzureWebJobsDashboard = $AzFunctionAppStorageAccountConnectionString;
    AzureWebJobsStorage = $AzFunctionAppStorageAccountConnectionString;
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~4";
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "dotnet";
}
```

And also make sure that the storage account connection string you provided in the function is same as here providing.

And then you can navigate to Kudu API to check the `wwwroot` folder is exist or not.

[image]

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **SO THREAD**|[***Powershell command Publish-AzWebApp not publishing apllication***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589817/powershell-command-publish-azwebapp-not-publishing-apllication)
- **BLOG**|[***How to Deploy Azure Function Apps With Powershell***](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deploy-azure-function-apps-with-powershell).